# Advanced installer parsing XML painfully slow

Tags: xml

is there a way to disable the parsing of xml, i want to make advanced installer treat the xml just like regular files rather than xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this installer support execution of commands? If yes, just rename all xml files to .xml.bin and rename them during or directly after the installation. This should prevent any parsing of the files.